# PHP router throwing an error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, routes

I am creating a very basic PHP routing/controller, just for learning purposes over anything else. Having used Laravel for some projects I really love its routing feature so I wanted to replicate something similar.

```
$route->map('/', function() {
    echo 'Hello World!';
});

$route->map('/', array('uses' => 'PagesController@index'));

$route->start();
```

Th first method works great, I believe it is an anonymous function. The second method I can create a file called PagesController.php with the following code:

```
Class PagesController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

This also works, but it throws an error:

`Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/git/Codingcats-Blog/classes/Route.php on line 40`

Here is my entire routing class:

```
    class Route
    {
        private $request = array();
        private $basePath = '/';

        function map($request, $params)
        {
            if (array_key_exists('uses', $params))
            {
                $parts = explode('@', $params['uses']);

                $controller = $parts[0];
                $method = $parts[1];

                if (!file_exists(PATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php'))
                    exit('Controller: ' . $controller . ' does not exist.');

                require_once PATH . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php';

                $controller = new $controller;

                if (method_exists($controller, $method))
                    $this->request[$request] = $controller->$method(); // ??????
            }
            else
            {
                $this->request[$request] = $params;
            }


        }

        function start()
        {
            $path = array_key_exists('PATH_INFO', $_SERVER) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : $this->basePath;
            $this->request[$path]();
        }
    }
```

I am unsure of the line with the `// ??????` though I can't get my head around it as both of the mapping methods end up at a function, and both work, just the second throwing the error as well.

I can call the function directly with `$controller->$method();` but then I get `Notice: Undefined index: / in...`

Advice appreciated :)

Comment: So, have you checked values of `$controller` and `$method`?

Comment: Yeah, in the above example $controller = PagesController and $method = index